Trying to generate unique match pairing for each team similar to 2024/25 UEFA Champion League Swiss system format
I'm trying to make a tournament pairing similar to the new UEFA Champion League format. There are 36 teams competing in the league phase. They are divided into 4 pots. Each team will play 8 matches (2 opponents from each pot). That adds up to 144 matches in total. I have a hard time coming up a function with good backtracking logic. Here is my failed code:
https://jsfiddle.net/4cgm1Lo8/5/
const pots = [
    ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9"],
    ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8","B9"],
    ["C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8","C9"],
    ["D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8","D9"],
];

const MATCH_COUNT = 144;
const MAX_ROUNDS = 8

function run() {
    const teamIds = _.flatten(pots)
    return teamIds.reduce((matches,thisTeamId) => {
        for (let round = 0; round < MAX_ROUNDS; round++) {
            const thisTeamMatches = matches.filter(match => match.includes(thisTeamId))
            if (thisTeamMatches.length >= MAX_ROUNDS) {
                break;
            }
            const pool = teamIds.filter(poolTeamId => {
                const encounteredBefore = thisTeamMatches.find(match => match.includes(poolTeamId))
                const potEncounterCount = thisTeamMatches.filter(match => {
                    const opponentId = match.find(m => m != thisTeamId)
                    return getTeamPot(opponentId, pots) === getTeamPot(poolTeamId, pots)
                })
                const poolTeamIdMatches = matches.filter(match => match.includes(poolTeamId))
                return poolTeamId != thisTeamId && !encounteredBefore && potEncounterCount.length < 2 && poolTeamIdMatches.length < MAX_ROUNDS
            })
            matches.push([thisTeamId, _.sample(pool)])
        }
        return matches
    }, [] as string[][])
}



function getTeamPot(teamId: string, pots: string[][]) {
    return pots.findIndex((pot) =>
        pot.find((potTeamId) => potTeamId === teamId),
    );
}

function getOpponent(yourTeamId: string, match: string[][]){
    return match.find(m => m != thisTeamId)                 
}

console.log(run())

This function is unable to create 144 matches. Some of the matches created have undefined opponents. The code really doesn't account for situations where it is unable to find a valid opponent for a team.
How would you make a backtracking method so that it can fill up some of the matchups that contains undefined opponent?

If you know you need to implement backtracking, what's the issue? Try it, and if your attempt is unsuccessful, then ask the question?

First problem: 36 teams divided into 4 pots would have nine teams per pot, not 8.

You can brute-force all possible team combinations and skip if a team already has 2 matches in a pot.
You have an error with your total match count, you have 32 teams, not 36, so your answer 128


const pots = [
    ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8"],
    ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8"],
    ["C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8"],
    ["D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8"],
];

let set = new Set, counts = {}, matches = [], potMatchCount = 2;

const shuffle = arr => {
  const copy = arr.slice();
  return Array.from({length: arr.length}, () => copy.splice(Math.random()*copy.length|0, 1)[0]);
};

const push = (a, b) => {
  if(a === b) return;
  const key = [a,b].sort().join('');
  const aKey = [a,b[0]].sort((a,b) => b.length-a.length).join('');
  const bKey = [a[0],b].sort((a,b) => b.length-a.length).join('');
  if((counts[aKey] ?? 0) < potMatchCount && (counts[bKey] ?? 0) < potMatchCount){
    if(set.has(key)) return;
    set.add(key);
    matches.push([a,b]);
    counts[aKey] = (counts[aKey] ?? 0) + 1;
    counts[bKey] = (counts[bKey] ?? 0) + 1;
  }
}

const teams = pots.flat();
const start = performance.now();
let trial = 0;
while(trial++ < 100){
  counts = {}, set.clear(), matches.length = 0;
  for(const a of shuffle(teams)){
    for(const b of shuffle(teams)){
      push(a,b);
    }
  }
  if(matches.length === 128) break;
}

console.log('milliseconds spent:', performance.now() - start);
console.log('total matches:', matches.length);
console.log('trials:', trial);
//console.log(JSON.stringify(matches));

const grouped = pots.flat().map(team => [team, matches.filter(arr => arr.includes(team)).map(arr => arr.filter(t => t !== team)[0])]);
grouped.forEach(team => console.log(team[0], ':', ...team[1].sort()));
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important}




Thanks for your suggestion. I'm playing with your code. Also, I just corrected the pots after someone in the comment points out that each pot should have 9 opponents (36 / 4).

My actual implementation somehow works by placing my own push() method in a while loop and clearing the entire round of matches and shuffling the teams in every round. This is the pseudo example (Not working in this fiddle): https://jsfiddle.net/3qryotxd/5/ . Not efficient at all and there seems to be a risk of infinite loop.  Backtracking is too complicated for me. Hope anyone can figure this out.

@RedGiant i've shuffled teams and with no more than 100 trials i'm able to get all teams playing 8 matches. Total match count should 128, since you have 32 teams, not 36
